# Rendering JavaScript file in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem with rendering JavaScript file in _Layout.cshtml.

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Custom/productsSuggests.js")"></script>
}
```

When I paste it to `Index.cshtml (Home)` it works, but only on this page. I need this script to work globally. I have partial view `SearchBox` in `HomeViews` catalog, and Controller Action in `HomeController`.

Comment: Scripts section is part of _Layout, you have to put this script in _Layout in head section of the document

Comment: Here you define a section called `Scripts`. Do you actually render it later with `RenderSection`? Are you sure you need a section in the first place given that you're putting this into layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are in the `_Layout.cshtml` view, it is likely the top level view. A `section` is a placeholder in a parent view.

Instead of your current code, try

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Custom/productsSuggests.js")
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Layout.cshtml you can use: `@Scripts.Render("YOUR BUNDLES")`

When will be add layout to another page this bundle will be global work.